# saving variables obtained from awk, for later use (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Having `credentials` file like this one:

```
db: db_name
user: username
password: password
```

After this command has been run:

```
awk '$1 ~ /db:|user:|password:/ { print $2 }' credentials \
| while read line; do c+=($line); done;
```

, I won't have a possibility to echo out my `${c[@]}` array, because pipe process has terminated, and variable is gone. How would I manage to save that after `while` loop is terminated, so that I could use elements of that `c` array, as credentials for example in following command:

```
mysql -u ${c[1]} -p${c[2]} ${c[0]} < file.sql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all:

```
$ c=( $( awk '$1 ~ /db:|user:|password:/ { print $2 }' file ) )
$ echo "${c[0]}"
db_name
$ echo "${c[1]}"
username
$ echo "${c[2]}"
password
```

Comment: Just what I was about to post. This is the most intuitive solution to me.

Comment: You are right, I thought because I already accepted the other one, but this solution is so elegant..

Comment: Fairly sure, there's a loop :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use pipe since it creates a sub process and all the variable created under it will not be available in parent shell. Use process substitution instead:

```
while read -r line; do 
    c+=($line)
done < <(awk '$1 ~ /db:|user:|password:/ { print $2 }' credentials)
```

Comment: Thank you, given that yours solution is pretty similiar to that of @Blue Moon, I marked his answer as accepted, because he was few seconds faster poster :)

Comment: Difference is [command substitution vs process substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416570/command-substitution-vs-process-substitution)

Comment: I know that, you have `fd` in place of `<(...)`, and bellow is command that executes giving line by line as `herestring` to while read, is your method faster, or better in some particular way?

Comment: [Yes as per this Q&A process substitution seems to be substantially faster](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/performance-differences-between-pipelines-and-process-substitution)

Comment: Oh I didn't intend to make you change your decision, it was just an academic discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redirecting it to pipe you could do:

```
while read line; do 
  c+=($line)
done <<<"$(awk '$1 ~ /db:|user:|password:/ { print $2 }' credentials)"
```

Now the array `c` will be available even after the loop exited.

However, you could directly read from the file `credentials` instead of using `awk` as you seem to be using `awk` only for splitting the line, which you could in bash itself:

```
while read line; do 
  line=${line##*:}
  c+=($line)
done <credentials
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do the whole thing in awk:

```
$ awk -F ': ' '{a[$1]=$2}END{system("echo mysql -u " a["user"] " -p" a["password"] " " a["db"] " < file.sql")}' file
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too, after posting here my question. Good solution, to use END block and system call

Comment: But you trimmed of my conditional statement, that `credentials` file holds much more than those three lines ;) Oh I see now, it will still work, because of associative array, sorry.

Comment: Extra lines in the file shouldn't cause any problem. To be honest, I don't think that there's much advantage to any of these approaches over simply parsing the file into variables.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant `db=$(awk '/^db:/{print $2}' file)`, etc.

Comment: Oh yes, if I would use a script like solution, but I wanted one-liner, because I will run that often as bash alias.

Answer (score 0):

credentials.txt (text file):

```
db: db_name
user: username
password: password
```

You can just assign the variables in awk- then after processing all rows in the the credentials file (or stdin), print out the command you want to run and pipe it to the shell to execute it.

```
cat credentials.txt|awk '/db/{db=$2} /username/{username=$2} /password/{password=$2} \
END{print "mysql -u "username" -p "password" "db" < file.sql"}' |sh
```

That will print:
    mysql -u username -p password db_name < file.sql

Then pass it to the shell and execute the query.